# Ocultar y mostrar de acuerdo al estado AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Tengo dos Botones de alta y Baja, quiero que al inicio cuando todos sean **true** solo se vea el boton de **Baja** y si alguno esta en **FALSE** se vea el  boton de **Alta**

```
<table class="table table-sm" ng-init="GetData()">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Dirección</th>
            <th>Estado</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="l in List">
            <td>{{l.Direccion}}</td>
            <td><i ng-class="l.Estado ? 'btn btn-info btn-sm' : 'btn btn-danger btn-sm'"><b>{{l.Estado ? 'Activo' : 'Inactivo'}}</b></i></td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" ng-click="VerIglesia(l.Id)">
                    <span class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" ng-click="Editar(l.Id)">
                    <span class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>

                <button type="button" ng-hide="btnAlta" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" ng-click="Alta(l.Id)">
                    <span class="fa fa-angle-up" aria-hidden="true"></span>Alta
                </button>

                <button type="button" ng-hide="btnBaja" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" ng-click="Baja(l.Id)">
                    <span class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>Baja
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui puedo  ver a unos que estan activos y otros Inactivos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Algo como esto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con “cuando todos sean true”? ¿Podrías escribir tu código javascript? "Este mensaje te lo dejó el usuario byrdEmanuel"

Comment: @byrdEmanuel me refierocuando vienen mis direcciones en la lista para mostrar hay algunos que vienen con true y otros con false entonce para cada uno mostrar el boton  que correspondo  y no mostrar los dos botones ***TRUE = btnBaja y FALSE = btnAlata***

Comment: podrias explicar con algun debug o un jsfiddle para poder ayudar?

Comment: @jsonencode ahora si?

Comment: @shadow ahora si?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si entiendo bien tus botones dependen de la propiedad `.Estado` de cada elemento de tu lista. Siendo asi tu HTML deberia quedar algo como:

```
<button type="button" ng-hide="l.Estado" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" ng-click="Alta(l.Id)">
    <span class="fa fa-angle-up" aria-hidden="true"></span>Alta
</button>

<button type="button" ng-show="l.Estado" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" ng-click="Baja(l.Id)">
    <span class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>Baja
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Usa en los dos botones que quieres:

```
<button ng-hide="l.Estado">
  <span></span>Alta
</button>
<button ng-show="l.Estado">
  <span></span>Baja
</button>
```

Esto debería funcionar.

(Omití algo del código para mostrar solo lo relevante en la pregunta)

Comment: Cuidado que eso no son comillas dobles.

Answer (score 2):

Para mi deberias realizar un ng-if en tu consulta

Entonces cuando tengas :

```
            <button type="button" ng-hide="btnBaja" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" ng-if="aplicar-condicional">
                <span class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>Baja
            </button>
```

Puedes diferenciar la condicion utiizando la funcion ng-if.

Saludos capo.

Answer (score 2):

Por qué no agregar una clase al atributo [disabled]?

**En HTML:**

```
<button ng-disabled="!l.Estado">
  <span></span>Alta
</button>
<button ng-disabled="l.Estado">
  <span></span>Baja
</button>
```

En CSS:

```
button[disabled] {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```